# Concatenação diferente ?

Tags: javascript, html

Galera estou começando a programar tem pouco tempo e tenho de fazer um cadastro só que eu quero que as informações digitadas pelo usuário como o nome, e-mail e idade apareçam através de um "alert" depois que ele clicar no botão "Aceitar".

Meus arquivos HTML e Javascript já estão "interligados", eu não sei se é possível fazer desse jeito, se não for me apresente a melhor forma de fazer isso utilizando apenas HTML e Javascript, e se for por favor me mostrem como.

> Meu arquivo HTML

```
    <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
    <input type="text" name="nome" size="20" maxlength="20" placeholder="Seu nome"/><br><br>
    <label for="senha">Senha:</label>
    <input type="password" name="senha" size="20" maxlength="25" placeholder="Sua senha"/><br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Aceitar" onClick="aceitar()">
    <a class="none" href=javascript:history.back();><input type="button" value="Cancelar"></input></a>

</form>
```

> Meu arquivo JS

```
function aceitar(){
    alert("Aqui seria a concatenação")   
 }
```

No aguardo
Att,
Lone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A concatenação é simples, basta usar o `+`, que é contextual (soma numéricos e concatena *strings*).

Para facilitar a vida, é interessante usar um `id` nos elementos:

```
<label for="nome">Nome:</label>
<input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" maxlength="20" placeholder="Seu nome"/><br><br>
<label for="senha">Senha:</label>
<input type="password" id="senha" name="senha" maxlength="25" placeholder="senha"/><br><br>
<input type="button" value="Aceitar" onClick="aceitar()">
```

Assim, você pode usar o `document.getElementById` para acessar os campos, e consequentemente, seu valor com `.value`

```
function aceitar() {
    var nome = document.getElementById('nome');   // Aqui pegamos o campo, e não seu valor
    var senha = document.getElementById('senha');
    // em seguida usaremos o .value para pegar o valor dos campos
    alert('Seu nome é ' + nome.value + 'e sua senha é ' + senha.value)

    // no caso especifico, poderiamos ter feito assim tambem:
    // var nome= document.getElementById('nome').value;
    // var senha = document.getElementById('senha').value;
    // alert('Seu nome é ' + nome + 'e sua senha é ' + senha)
}
```

Tem outras formas de acessar elementos sem `id`, mas o `id` facilita a leitura e simplifica o acesso. Poderíamos, por exemplo, ter usado `document.getElementsByName`, mas é retornada uma lista de nós, em vez de um elemento único, pois os nomes podem ser repetidos num mesmo documento.

Veja funcionando no **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/bacco/pen/GrjKMQ)**.

Comment: Eu lembro que também é possível usar esse "getElementById" junto da função onClick com imagens, pois também vou precisar que ao usuário clicar na imagem o programa chame outra e se ele clicar novamente voltar a imagem anterior ou seja vão ser duas imagens.Qual seria a maneira correta de se fazer isso ? E obrigado pelo resposta anterior.

Comment: o getElementById serve para referenciar qualquer elemento do DOM, o que você vai fazer com o elemento depois só depende do contexto. Quanto ao que você perguntou, depende bastante. Seria o caso de abrir uma pergunta nova e tentar explicar o mais detalhadamente possível. Mas dê uma pesquisada antes pelo site, pq já tem algumas perguntas respondidas sobre galerias de imagem.

Comment: Eu dei uma olhada sobre galerias mas não tem exatamente o que eu quero, o que eu queria era fazer um efeito que ao clicar na imagem ela mudava de cor chamando outra e se clicasse de novo ela mudaria para a cor que estava no começo ou seja a mesma imagem.Mas no estou necessitando disso com urgência, outro dia volto a fazer outro tópico no entanto você conseguindo me ajudar por aqui já adiantaria.

Comment: @LoneTonberry me parece que o que você perguntou foi respondido, se tiver alguma dúvida nova abra uma nova pergunta.